# Toggling among QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to toggle among QWidgets. In the code below, I'd like `sceneWidget` to show either `view1` or `view2`, depending on which button has been pressed.

[image: scene1]

[image: scene2]

But the code hardly does that. What is wrong? (Aside from the very ugly global variables, which I leave for a next step.)

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

QGraphicsView* getView(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(new QGraphicsEllipseItem(x,y,w,h));
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    return view;
}

QVBoxLayout* rightVbox;
QGraphicsView* view1;
QGraphicsView* view2;

void c1() {
    rightVbox->insertWidget(0, view1);
}

void c2() {
    rightVbox->insertWidget(0, view2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    view1 = getView(0,0,100,50);
    view2 = getView(0,0,50,100);

    QWidget* mainWidget = new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout* hbox = new QHBoxLayout(mainWidget);

    QWidget* buttonsWidget = new QWidget;
    hbox->addWidget(buttonsWidget);
    QVBoxLayout* leftVbox = new QVBoxLayout(buttonsWidget);
    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("Scene 1", buttonsWidget);
    QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton("Scene 2", buttonsWidget);
    leftVbox->addWidget(button1);
    leftVbox->addWidget(button2);

    QWidget* sceneWidget = new QWidget;
    hbox->addWidget(sceneWidget);

    rightVbox = new QVBoxLayout(sceneWidget);
    rightVbox->insertWidget(0, view1);

    QObject::connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, c1);
    QObject::connect(button2, &QPushButton::clicked, c2);

    mainWidget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a QStackedWidget for that purpose.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: The usual comparison between QTabWidget and QStackedWidget makes me wonder whether either is suited when one does not have an upper bound to the number of tabs or stacks. Are you aware whether QStackedWidget is suited if the widgets number in the hundreds or thousands?

Comment: A stacked widget definitely scaled better to multiple widgets compared to a tab widget. Try it out, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you should be able to simply use `show` and `hide` on the two items. 
Quoting from the `QBoxLayout` page:

> Calling QWidget::hide() on a widget also effectively removes the widget from the layout until QWidget::show() is called.

I was able to switch between the two widgets with the buttons by doing this in `main()`:

```
[...]
rightVbox = new QVBoxLayout(sceneWidget);
rightVbox->insertWidget(0, view1);
rightVbox->insertWidget(0, view2);
view2->hide();
[...]
```

and then change your two functions `c1` and `c2` to:

```
void c1() {
  view1->show();
  view2->hide();
}

void c2() {
  view2->show();
  view1->hide();

}
```

Does this do what you had in mind?